# Continuous wave-like animation from wave line SVG

Tags: javascript, css, svg, css-animations

I have an SVG that is a wavy line built with Adobe Illustrator and I'm trying to add a continuous wave-like animation to it.

I've tried vivus.js and was able to get the draw animation working but not continuously.

How can I start something like this?

Any answer will work whether it's pure CSS, JS, or both.

Here is the svg

```
<svg id="wave" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 456.7 39.9" style="enable-background:new 0 0 456.7 39.9;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .st69{fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:12;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
</style>
    <path class="st69" d="M4.2,33.2c0.1-0.1,7-6.9,15.9-13.8C27.7,13.7,38.7,6,47.5,6c7.5,0,14,6.6,20.3,12.9l0.4,0.4
    c6.8,6.9,14.6,14.6,24.6,14.6c9.9,0,17.7-7.8,24.5-14.6l0.5-0.5C124,12.5,130.5,6,137.9,6c7.5,0,13.9,6.5,20.2,12.9l0.4,0.4
    c6.8,6.9,14.6,14.6,24.5,14.6c10,0,17.8-7.8,24.6-14.6l0.5-0.5C214.4,12.5,220.9,6,228.4,6c7.5,0,14,6.5,20.2,12.9l0.4,0.4
    c6.8,6.9,14.5,14.6,24.5,14.6c9.9,0,17.7-7.8,24.5-14.6l0.3-0.3c6.3-6.4,12.9-13,20.5-13c7.5,0,14.1,6.6,20.4,13l0.3,0.3
    c6.8,6.9,14.6,14.6,24.5,14.6c9.9,0,17.6-7.8,24.5-14.6l0.2-0.2C395.1,12.6,401.6,6,409.2,6c8.7,0,19.8,7.7,27.3,13.4
    c8.9,6.8,15.9,13.7,16,13.8"/>
</svg>
```

and the JS Fiddle link [is here](https://jsfiddle.net/hhr6y3s9/).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I hope this will help you. Play a little bit with the values or add the SVG wave as background, repeat it and change the `background-position`.

```css
@keyframes wave {
  0% { 
    left: -80px; 
  }
  100% { 
    left: 0; 
  }
}

.container {
  width: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.container svg {
  position: relative;
  left: -50px;
  width: 200px;
  animation: wave 2s linear infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg id="wave" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 456.7 39.9" style="enable-background:new 0 0 456.7 39.9;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .st69{fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:12;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
</style>
    <path class="st69" d="M4.2,33.2c0.1-0.1,7-6.9,15.9-13.8C27.7,13.7,38.7,6,47.5,6c7.5,0,14,6.6,20.3,12.9l0.4,0.4
 c6.8,6.9,14.6,14.6,24.6,14.6c9.9,0,17.7-7.8,24.5-14.6l0.5-0.5C124,12.5,130.5,6,137.9,6c7.5,0,13.9,6.5,20.2,12.9l0.4,0.4
 c6.8,6.9,14.6,14.6,24.5,14.6c10,0,17.8-7.8,24.6-14.6l0.5-0.5C214.4,12.5,220.9,6,228.4,6c7.5,0,14,6.5,20.2,12.9l0.4,0.4
 c6.8,6.9,14.5,14.6,24.5,14.6c9.9,0,17.7-7.8,24.5-14.6l0.3-0.3c6.3-6.4,12.9-13,20.5-13c7.5,0,14.1,6.6,20.4,13l0.3,0.3
    c6.8,6.9,14.6,14.6,24.5,14.6c9.9,0,17.6-7.8,24.5-14.6l0.2-0.2C395.1,12.6,401.6,6,409.2,6c8.7,0,19.8,7.7,27.3,13.4
 c8.9,6.8,15.9,13.7,16,13.8"/>
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: this is exactly what i was looking for

Answer (score 9):

Aside from css tricks, you could use Math.sin with interval, apply this to Bezier Curve (loop & join into attribute string) and it's done.

```js
function anim(){
 document.querySelectorAll('svg circle').forEach((c,i)=>c.setAttribute('cy',50+Math.sin(performance.now()/1000+i)*25))
}
setInterval(anim,20)
```

```html
<svg id="wave" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 456 100" style="enable-background:new 0 0 456 100;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .st69{fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:12;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
</style>
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="4"  fill="red" />
    <circle cx="100" cy="50" r="4"  fill="red" />
    <circle cx="150" cy="50" r="4"  fill="red" />
    <circle cx="200" cy="50" r="4" fill="red" />
    <circle cx="250" cy="50" r="4"  fill="red" />
    <circle cx="300" cy="50" r="4"  fill="red" />
    <circle cx="350" cy="50" r="4"  fill="red" />
    <circle cx="400" cy="50" r="4" fill="red" />
</svg>
```

Comment: thank you sir, this helps. I already accepted another answer but i gave you an upvote